# Is reusing an API across wildly different targets a good practice?

Tags: api-design, game-development

Let's say I have something called "Actuators". Each "Actuator" may have capabilities associated with it. Should I reuse it wherever it fits, or should I create entirely separate kinds of actuators for each kind of target?

I have block targets, I have item targets, I have entity targets and I have command targets.

An actuator may have capabilities associated with it, e.g. "can open GUIs" (normal players), "can ride entities" (normal players, entities), "has position" (normal players, fake players, entities), "can display text" (normal players, console), etc.

Is it a good idea to reuse such an API across multiple targets, even if such targets may be wildly different from eachother? Would this reduce maintenance cost? Would this make implementation a pain?

Comment: Library and API design for reuse is an extremely broad topic and can IMHO not explained here in one short answer on Programmers. I recommend to google for "library api design", and you will find a lot of tutorials, blogs and articles.

Comment: This isn't library reuse, this is API reuse. A single class/object/thingy being reused in multiple methods for wildly different objects/entities/thingies.

Comment: ... and the answer to your question is "it depends". On how the API is designed, how your application's overall design, on the responsibility of the component you want to reuse, on the requirements of the different "targets" for your component, and how stable those requirements are, on what those "targets" really are. Sometimes it can also depend on organizational factors like who is responsible for maintaining which component of the application, and so on. There are books written about that topic.

Comment: This is for a Minecraft clone, to put it as simply as possible.

Comment: Well, is what you have in mind small and simple enough you can show us some example code? Maybe that will make your question more clearer and focussed. I am not still sure you really talk of API reuse (your "Actuator" beeing only an interface) or component reuse (your "Actuator" beeing a class which has obviously has to live somewhere, typically in a library). Words like "it is something" are not very precise, you know?

Comment: It's basically an ECS (entity component system). The code for even a basic ECS is a bit... big... at least compared to the question text. (And this isn't counting the examples of usage/implementation.)

Comment: Not the code of whole system, of course - just a few lines to clarify what you really mean by API reuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about interface design.  An interface defines how you talk to whatever you're talking to.  Reusing the same interface means you don't have to talk any differently than you did when talking to that other thing.  This new thing may do something different when you talk to it but what you say to it is the same stuff you were saying before.

This way I can swap out what is being talked to because what is doing the talking doesn't even know what it's talking to.  That's a good thing.  The fancy term for this is polymorphism.  It's also good thing.  Done this way you aren't doing it with inheritance, you're doing it with composition.

This is all well and good provided your interface lets you say all you need to say.  This can go sideways when you realize, oh we need to be able to say that to.  Oh what about this.  Before you know it you have a dozen interfaces in your API and all do half or three quarters of what the rest do.

I deeply believe the thing that does the talking (traditionally called a client) should define what the interface is.  What does the listening (a service) is really something you can think about later as long as you allow that thing to be anything.

This attitude can seem strange if you were asked to write the part that listens not the part that talks but I implore you to at least write one thing that talks before you write the part that listens.  Otherwise you end up listening for kitchen sinks that never come.

The client owns the interface. The service does not.  When designing the interface, think about the client. The fancy term for this is the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

In other words as a client, I don't give a damn how different your targets (services) are.  I care if they do what I need them to do when I tell them to do it.  I don't care how they do it.  And so long as it's nothing to do with me I really don't care what they really do so long as it's what they were supposed to do.  Really, I don't know what they do.  I don't want to know. Just go do it.

Comment: I really like the way you answered this question.  Any books you'd recommend for interface design?  Or books on best practices for object-oriented design and abstraction in general?

Comment: We don't recommend books here.  I will tell you that you'd be well served to look up the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles and [Tell, don't ask](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:tell_don_t_ask_information_expert).  There are many good books to read and sites to search.

Comment: Good to know, and that looks like a great starting point.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @CandidedOrange's very good answer:

> Is it a good idea to reuse such an API across multiple targets, even if such targets may be wildly different from each other?

If you find commonality across vastly different objects, especially across very different kinds of objects, this suggests an interface hierarchy rather than a simpler flat interface or class structure.  Using interface (and/or class) hierarchy we can have some extremely general stuff at the top, and specialized stuff at each sub-level.

So, the idea is to add funtionality at the right place in the hierarchy, which sometimes means creating a new level somewhere.  Sometimes, later, we discover that something is more general that we'd thought, so we the move it upwards in the hierarchy.  Other times we discover something is more specialized and should move down in the hierarchy, and possibly to its own level of the hierarchy.  (All of these might be considered refactoring.)

The goal is to provide clients with very usable and coherent abstractions: abstractions they can use directly, without reaching underneath or around (such having to test the type of an object).

> Would this reduce maintenance cost? Would this make implementation a pain?

Putting your abstractions at the right level of generalization/specialization, IMHO is key to having maintainable object-oriented software.  It tends to decouple clients and implementations, which eases maintenance.  When the class hierarchy is not factored well, you have much more pain in adding new functionality.  Still, you can't expect to get it right immediately, so this is one reason why we alternate refactoring (reshaping existing functionality) with adding new functionality.

Comment: +1 for commonality.  I'm no longer a fan of hierarchies though.  Prefer decoupled behaviors and value objects.